# Insert data into table from another table (from another connection)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, migration, database-migration

I am curious if I can insert the data of a table from another connection to a table which i created.

I created the table `GPS` with the same column-names... etc. in the connection `host-abc1.de`

and now i want to fill in the data from another table (which also is called GPS and has the same columns, etc.) but this on another connection `host-abc2.de`

can I do something like this?

```
INSERT INTO host-abc1.de_NameOfSchema1_GPS, SELECT * FROM host-abc2.de_NameOfSchema2_GPS;
```

thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Linked Server in order to work with data and objects from multiple sources. 
The link below gives you detail about how to create a linked server and work with it -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: does this apply also for MYSQL ?

Comment: Yes, it applies to MYSQL as well. Its a little bit different how you configure it. This might help - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4577/create-a-linked-server-to-mysql-from-sql-server/